# Running the ADO.net program at regular interval

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, ado.net

I have a sql serevr database in a remote system .I am using ADO.net to bring that database table values into my local mysql server .

Now i want to fetch data from remote db into my local db every 15 min .I think this will involve running the program every 15 min.Please suggest if there is any better way .I want to make it automatic.

I tried with putting the package.dtsx in schedule task . It doesnt work .I think we can make an exe file and then run it

Can you tell me how do i make an exe file?

How do i do this.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at scheduled tasks or windows services.

Comment: So i can add package.dtsx in schedule tasks and run it every 15 min .I can close the visual studio tool too ..right ?? sorry for being novice

Comment: adding the package.dtsx file doesnt work . I guess we need to create an exe file and then run . Can u tell how do i create an exe file .

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged your question with Visual Studio 2008, I'll assume you have that.

Create a new project of type Console Application. If you add your code to that project and compile it, the result will be a .exe file which you can run as a Scheduled task.

However, since you are talking about a .dtsx package, another option would be to add your .dtsx package as a scheduled job in the server you are trying to import data to.

Read [this on how you schedule a job](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/23/sql-server-running-ssis-package-in-scheduled-job/) in SQL Server.